# Updating an ActiveAdmin nested resource using inputs not located on the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I currently have a form for a nested resource in one of my activeadmin pages:

```
    f.inputs "Courses" do
      f.has_many :registrations, :allow_destroy => true, new_record: true do |tc|
        tc.input :course
        tc.input :semester
      end
    end
```

This is for a **student** resource.  A **student** has many **course_offerings** through **registrations**.  However, I didn't want users to select the **course_offering** directly from a menu (Since there will be many repeats of the same course each year).  Instead there is an input for **course** and **semester**.  **course** and **semester** are instance variables on the **registration** model.  They are set in the form, then the correct **course_offering** is found in an after save hook and associated with the **registration**.  The code is as follows:

```
def semester=(s)
  @semester = s.to_i
end

def semester
  self.course_offering.semester
end

def course=(co)
  @course = co.to_i
end

def course
  self.course_offering.course
end

before_save :set_course_offering

def set_course_offering
  self.course_offering = CourseOffering.where(semester_id: @semester, course_id: @course).first
  #TODO: Handle case where no course offering is found
end
```

I am having two problems.  The first is that I get a nil pointer error when registrations table is empty.

> undefined method `course' for nil:NilClass

I have accepts_nested_attributes call in my **student** model.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrations, :allow_destroy => true
```

which is the only suggestion I get when looking up the error but still get it despite having that piece of code.  It seems to work fine when I remove the **course** and **semester** and replace it with a **course_offering** instead.

The next problem I have is that the student record does not save after hitting update.  I assume this is because I don't make any changes that write to the database when I only update the two **course** and **semester** instance variables only.  I either need to update another input or add the call to the semester= method.

Answer (score 0):

You get an `undefined method` error because when the registration table is empty there are no course offerings associated with your student, so in the accessor method for course you get `nil` for `self.course_offerings`. You could try this instead which takes the nil value into account:

```
def course
  self.course_offering.try(:course)
end
```

You don't need the `accept_nested_attributes_for` because you don't want to create or modify course offerings through students.

For your second problem: you're right about the dirty tracking. Your model is not saved because your student model has not been modified from the perspective of ActiveRecord. You need to flag an attribute (eg `course_offering`) as dirty by hand with the [`course_attribute_will_change!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) method before saving the model.

Although this situation looks like a good example to introduce form objects. There is a great library for that called [reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform).